# how to remove cell index when timer gets complete after 5 min ios swift 5 , when called api not repeat timeragain of same index

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, timer

I want to implement timer logic, when 5 min gets complete then my `Tableview` reload and its remove that particular index, I have tried not gets works, and timer get fast

```
//Timer ACtion Method
 @objc func timerAction() {
        
          if seconds>0 {
            seconds-=1
            minutes = String(format:"%02i",(seconds / 60))
            seconds1 = String(format:"%02i",(seconds % 60))
            print(minutes! + ":" + seconds1!)
            self.lblMin.text = minutes!
            self.lblSec.text = seconds1!
          } else {
              minutes = String(seconds / 60)
              seconds1 = String(seconds % 60)
              if minutes == "0" && seconds1 == "0" {
              
                timer.invalidate()
                btnReject.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                btnAccept.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
               // TBVC.InstancePending.arrPending.remove(at: intValue!)
                //tblData?.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: intValue!, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
               // TBVC.InstancePending.getTableBooking(strStatus: "0")
               // TBVC.InstancePending.strTap = "Pending"
               // TBVC.InstancePending.segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
                
               // tblData?.reloadData()
                
              }
            }
         }
```

Comment: what is the issue u faced

Comment: when i called my api then again remaining timer display.. my timer gets fast .. interval time is change automatically

Answer (score 0):

**Set Timer value nil, And check when API called then the timer will not pass any selector method**

```
@objc func timerAction() {
    
      if seconds>0 {
        seconds-=1
        minutes = String(format:"%02i",(seconds / 60))
        seconds1 = String(format:"%02i",(seconds % 60))
        print(minutes! + ":" + seconds1!)
        self.lblMin.text = minutes!
        self.lblSec.text = seconds1!
      } else {
          minutes = String(seconds / 60)
          seconds1 = String(seconds % 60)
          if minutes == "0" && seconds1 == "0" {
          
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            btnReject.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            btnAccept.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
           // TBVC.InstancePending.arrPending.remove(at: intValue!)
            //tblData?.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: intValue!, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
           // TBVC.InstancePending.getTableBooking(strStatus: "0")
           // TBVC.InstancePending.strTap = "Pending"
           // TBVC.InstancePending.segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
            
           // tblData?.reloadData()
            
          }
        }
     }
```

=====================================

**2nd method to implement timer:-**

*Initialize Variable*

```
var timer:Timer?
var totalMinut:Int = 2
var totalSecond:Int = 120
var timeLeft = 120
```

*Add timer function*

```
 func setupTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func onTimerFires() {
    
       var minutes: Int
       var seconds: Int

       if totalSecond == 1 {
           timer?.invalidate()
           timer = nil
       }
       totalSecond = totalSecond - 1
       minutes = (totalSecond) / 60
       seconds = (totalSecond) % 60
       timerLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
}
```

Call "setUpTimer" method where you have required. In my case, I have called it in the "viewDidLoad" method of a view controller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    setupTimer()
}
```

Comment: my timer gets fast

Comment: Hi, I have added the 2nd method in my post. Please use it. I have implemented it for two minutes(logic) and it works properly in my project.

Comment: when i refresh my page then time get fast automatically with diff interval time

Comment: On the page refresh method set timer = nil, && timer?.invalidate(). And again Call "setupTimer()" method when you want to re-initialize it. (As I have set up in method 2nd solution)

Comment: how to implemnet perfect timer in tableview cell .. i have tried lot of solution but timer get fast when table reload . i dont know how to solve this issue

Comment: Means If the table view reloads, timer show 2 seconds when 1-second laps, in reality, something like that. Okay, let me Implement this.

Comment: yeah , time exactly 2 min but timer get fast and over two min in 3 sec duration